# Not able to post to facebook wall

Tags: ios, facebook

In my iOS app ,some event details are posted to user's facebook wall.Since it requires facebook app review,I have submitted app twice but its rejected saying that your app is using third party dialog and need not require any permission from facebook.But i am not able to post from different user ids.Only user added as developer/tester is able to post to facebook.I have no clue what to do with this issue.Please help

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're requesting the `publish_actions` permission. This permission is subject to Login Review. If you are rejected, you will not be able to use this permission with other users than the app's admins/developers/testers.

It's all documented in the Facebook docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review